# What is difference between SavedStateHandle and rememberSaveable?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel, android-savedstate

As far as I know, with Android Compose,

`SavedStateHandle` is used with `ViewModel` and follows the `ViewModel` lifecycle and key-value map and it can be used as flow.

`rememberSaveable` is used with variables in `Composable` and follows the Composable lifecycle.

And both are used to prevent data loss when the activity gets destroyed by the system.

Are there any other differences?

Comment: SavedStateHandle can used if process is destroyed by the system in case of low memeory situations(process death). rememberSaveable i used to save state during configuration change. have a look at https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/viewmodels-with-saved-state-jetpack-navigation-data-binding-and-coroutines-df476b78144e although its not for compose

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the answer from [Google's documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state-saving):

> The API to use depends on where the state is held and the logic that
> it requires. For state that is used in UI logic, use `rememberSaveable`.
> For state that is used in business logic, if you hold it in a
> `ViewModel`, save it using `SavedStateHandle`.